# for loop and if statement, taking variable and storing it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

```
for (counter = 0; counter < records.length; counter++) {
    if(userEntered.value == records[counter]){
        alert("help");  
        value = true;
        comparedZipCode = records[counter];
    }
}
```

i'm not able to get the value entered by user to now compare it with the record.

its searching the zip code but it has nothing to compare it to. maybe .value isnt supposed to be there?

here is the whole code:

```
       records = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();




    userEntered = prompt("Search students in current zipcode:");

    userEntered = Number(userEntered);


while (records.readNextRecord()) {


    firstName   = records.getSampleFirstName();
    lastName    = records.getSampleLastName();
    gender      = records.getSampleGender();
    zipCode     = records.getSampleZipCode();


    for (counter = 0; counter < records.readNextRecord(zipCode); counter++) {

        if(userEntered.value == records.readNextRecord[counter]){

            value = true;

            comparedZipCode[counter] += records.readNextRecord[counter];


            }

    }

}
    //test feature
    document.write(comparedZipCode);
```

Comment: What do you mean "store it into the empty array variable". Can you give an example of what you have in `records` as well as an example output illustrating what you want to achieve. Also as a side note, I would suggest using a Set or object to store your records that way you have constant lookup and don't have to iterate to begin with.

Comment: we haven't learned about sets or objects. this is javascript basic basic.

all i'm trying to do is have the data that was entered from user. then have it search the "record" once if finds all the records that match the numbered entered, take it and store it into an empty array or should it be. 

comparedZipCode = "";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store it in comparedZipCode by declaring it as an array before you enter the loop.

```
var comparedZipCode = []
for (counter = 0; counter < records.length; counter++) {
    if(userEntered.value == records[counter]){
        alert("help");  
        value = true;
        comparedZipCode[counter] = records[counter];
    }
}
```

Comment: ^followed above.

works but for some reason its not printing any data out.

i checked to see if value returns true and it does.